# How to remove the opacity of a local icon in google map style?

Tags: google-maps

How can I remove the opacity/blend mode of the one-way icon in my google map style (Locales -> Icons (red arrow)). I can change the color, but not the rest.

[image: google map style]

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps styles [does not accept anything but HSL and HEX colors](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#hue-saturation-lightness) and as such, you cannot apply an opacity or blend mode to the icons in the map style (except for saturation, gamma, and lightness).

Comment: How can I remove the current opacity? As you can see, I put a red, but the arrows are pale.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be out of scope of the map styling.